# cant connect to tor network 2 mac

Tags: configuration

Last login: Mon Oct  5 23:12:01 on ttys000
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:02.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
15-10-05 23:17:02.300 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/Applications/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1" 
15-10-05 23:17:02.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
15-10-05 23:17:02.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
15-10-05 23:17:03.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
15-10-05 23:17:03.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
15-10-05 23:17:03.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
15-10-05 23:17:06.200 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '171.25.193.9:80'): It seems that our clock is behind by 2 hours, 54 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
15-10-05 23:17:06.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
15-10-05 23:17:06.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrap-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:02.300 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/Applications/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1" 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:02.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:02.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:03.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:03.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:03.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:06.200 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '171.25.193.9:80'): It seems that our clock is behind by 2 hours, 54 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:06.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:06.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:06.500 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '199.254.238.52:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 2 hours, 54 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:06.500 [WARN] Our clock is 2 hours, 42 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-10-06 06:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:06.500 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:23.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:23.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:23.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 15-10-05 23:17:23.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
-bash: 15-10-05: command not found
cesar-montanos-MacBook:~ cesarmontano$ 
here is a copy of my log.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly this: "Our clock is 2 hours, 42 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document".  Make sure your system's clock is correct. (You can check it at http://vancouver-webpages.com/time/ )

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.